# django on a vps - getting "model is already registered" when restarting server

Tags: python, django, django-models

asked this question over the weekend, but for some reason all replies have died. started it again as i now have new information

when i restart apache on my vps, i get

```
the model "category" is already registered
```

from init.py

i think this is because the object is getting discovered and registered twice.

i didn't think this would be an issue, it isn't in dev where i don't get these errors. also, i dont get the error the first time i run the server after a syncdb.

so upload code, syncdb, start apache, no error message. restart apache and the error message appears.

i can hide it, by commenting out the line that registers the model, but this means that the object doesn't appear in admin unless i uncomment the line and upload it after the admin site has loaded the first time.

this only appears to happen the first time after an apache reset, doesn't happen subsequent times.

anyone come across this before? using apache with mod_wsgi on debian, django 1.2.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message suggests that model registration code is being repeated. Are you registering your models in the models.py file? The recommended way is to write a separate admin.py file to register the models.

Comment: i now know that this is because the model is getting registered twice. i think this is because discover admin is registering the model as well as the code in init.py registering the model too.

Comment: what i need to do, is work out which files register the model and make one of them not.

or alternatively, write a codeblock which will try and register the model and if its already registered, unregister it, then register it again.

Comment: sometimes you may need to delete *.pyc files to solve the problem

Comment: Bahodir's comment was very useful for me. Post it as a new answer.

Comment: This happened to me when I was cleaning up a models.py file.  I inadvertently copied two models to a different place in my file without deleting the original models in the location I was moving them from.

Answer (score 1):

This can be due to the order with which you have subclassed other models. For instance, if you subclass both [Django-polymorphic's](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) `PolymorphicModel` and another model, e.g., Django-extensions' `TimeStampedModel`, you need to subclass `PolymorphicModel` first or it will raise this error:

```
class MyClass(TimeStampedModel, PolymorphicModel):  # Raises error
class MyClass(PolymorphicModel, TimeStampedModel):  # Does not raise error
```