# How to fix: "RuntimeWarning: Model <my_model> was already registered."

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, ipython

Since upgrading Django, I've been getting this error in iPython when I do imports:

> RuntimeWarning: Model 'docket.search' was already registered. Reloading models is not advised as it can lead to inconsistencies, most notably with related models.

I'm guessing this is some automatic feature of iPython, but is there an easy solution? Is this something I even need to solve?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302527/django-on-a-vps-getting-model-is-already-registered-when-restarting-server

Comment: Doesn't seem like a match. This is a problem that only seems to happen in ipython, so far, and only when you do imports.

Answer (score 38):

Exactly the same problem had happened to me. The problem was that I had defined a model twice! Removing one of them solved the problem.

Comment: 2 secs after reading your answer i was able to fix it. Automatic 'code refactoring' from my IDE was the cause. (We all know which one it is)

Comment: Yes duplicated models, I did it by mistake in git merge.

Comment: Ahh! The error I got was `AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'`. Turned out I had a duplicate model (from copying and pasting)

Answer (score 5):

Check in your models if you don't got a duplicate class model, sometimes when we make a rebase or merge in our existing branches, our code can be duplicated, i had the same problem, isn't a big deal.

Comment: in my case, it was exactly this. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error when mistakenly defining **2 of the same name models(classes)** in **"models.py"** as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(help_text=_("Required"), max_length=200)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have gotten this error because of automatic imports I had in my `__init__.py`. I had some old code that imported by signals there, and moving that import code to AppConfig instead fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

It is saying that you have  already registered the model before
Hence by deleting the second model or writing the code in the specified model is the solution for this .